# 301 Redirection Help for Moving New Domain with New Directory

Tags: seo, htaccess

I have a WordPress website on example.com with 500+ pages.

I need to move this site to newsite.com/blog/

I searched this on Google the whole day, but couldn't find how to write 301 for my requirements. Most tutorials are just for new domain. But I want to move to new domain with blog directory.

Comment: For sake of clarity, you want everything at `example.com` to be redirected to `newsite.com/blog/`, so if you presently had `example.com/blog` you'd want that redirected to `newsite.com/blog/blog/`, and nothing redirected to the root of `newsite.com`?

Comment: If that's the case, then try just adding `/blog/` to a RewriteRule, like:
`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: "Most tutorials are just for new domain." - But the principle is the same, you just add `blog/` to the URL-path? Do the old and new domains point to the same hosting? Since this is a WordPress site there is more to do than simply adding a redirect - you need to configure the domain in the site settings and make sure all instances of the old domain in the database have been changed. Presumably these stages have already been completed?